# Django flatpages raising 404 when DEBUG is False (404 and 500 templates exist)

Tags: django, django-flatpages, http-status-code-404

I'm using Django 1.1.1 stable. When `DEBUG` is set to `True` [Django flatpages](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/) works correctly; when `DEBUG` is `False` every flatpage I try to access raises a custom 404 error (my error template is obviously working correctly).

Searching around on the internet suggests creating 404 and 500 templates which I have done.

I've added to `FlatpageFallBackMiddleware` to middleware_classes and flatpages is added to installed applications. Any ideas how I can make flatpages work?

Answer (score 6):

The same happened to me until I found that the 404 view was sending a 200 status response. So all you have to do is add this in the view that handles your 404 response:

```
def 404_handler(request):    ...

    response = render_to_response('404.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 404
    return response
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add `FlatpageFallBackMiddleware` before `django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware`

and be sure, that your 404.html and 500.html are stored in the root of your templates dir `(eg: templates/404.html)`

Answer (score 0):

The key is checking the order of your middleware. Middleware is executed in top-down order on the way *in* (request and view) and in bottom-out order on the way *out* (response and exception). So if you are getting to your 404 handler on what should be a perfectly reasonable flatpage URL then something is catching the 404 before the flatpages middleware is getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error in a different context. The problem was caused by me changing file `urls.py` from

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
```

to

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import include, patterns
```

as suggested by `pylint`, but this omits handler404 and handler500 which are expected to be imported implicitly by import `*`.

so either adding those to import or just importing `*` as django documents suggest solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make an error handling view that prints a stacktrace `import traceback;traceback.print_exc()` instead of ignoring the error silently.